# Using method unorderly

Tags: c#

I would like to know if I can call methods or function unorderly.

For example like this :

```
public static class Employee
{
    int s=0;

    public int addOne()
    {
        return s++ ;
    }
}
```

And now What i need to do:

```
int sum = Employee.addOne()
                  .addOne()
                  .addOne();
```

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: Anyway, a static class cannot have instance methods or variables

Comment: Try compiling the code first, fix all the errors it has.

Comment: What does "unorderly" mean?

Comment: I think what you want to do is called Fluent interface. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C#

Answer (score 4):

Chaining calls (also called a "fluent syntax" or "fluent interface") is not uncommon in C#: in fact, LINQ, an important part of .NET library, [can be accessed using fluent syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq).
It requires a different method signature: rather than returning an `int`, you need to return `Employee`. Here is an example:

```
public class Employee // You cannot do this with a static class
{
    public int S {get; private set;}

    public Employee addOne()
    {
        S++ ;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Obviously, you would need to set up some alternative way of accessing the value of `s`, so the call would look like this:

```
var employee = new Employee();
int sum = employee.addOne()
              .addOne()
              .addOne()
              .S; // <<== Here is the change
```